# Angular2 directive wait for component to be initialised

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, components

I've got an wrapper component loading multiple components by using `createComponent` and in every component i want to append an canvas element. Now i figured there are a few ways of doing so, and with every way of doing i get kind of stuck.

**Number 1**

In the wrapper component access the child component (which i've not been able to do because nativeElement in `this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);` is a private property), and i need to know the child component is initialised (so i'll have to use a service for this).

**Number 2**

Create a directive and place the canvas element with in the loaded component: `<canvas projectCanvas class="overlay"></canvas>` Now i'm already able to access the template through the directive itself. (Which is great but kind of repetitive).

Only thing is the directive is constructed before the component's view is initialised, so i have to create an service that will keep track of the components status.

**Actual question**

How would you approach this? In my point of view there's no escaping a service, or is there a way to check if the view is initialised from the wrapper component?

**---------------Update------------------**

Tried to make a version with a service but `ngAfterViewInit` / `ngOnInit` seems not to work when the component is loaded by `createComponent` see [Pliunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wc3aIpC2S8lFOxAJgG9J?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

How did you try `ngAfterViewInit` ?

Did you try injecting the children components in the wrapper like so?

```
@Component({...})
export class WrapperComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  @ViewChildren(InnerComponent) innerComponents : QueryList<InnerComponent>;

   ngAfterViewInit(){
     this.innerComponents.forEach(c => c.doSomething());
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, `ngAfterViewInit` in the child component doesn't work when loaded with `createComponent`, the wrapper component does tho. And the viewChild in your example returns undefined, because i guess the child is not initialised yet.

Comment: In your plunkr, the ngAfterViewInit() of C2 is correctly called. But their is a typo, you assign true to `initialsed` instead of `initialised`.